# Delete row in gridview after confirmation message

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Previously in order to delete my record i will use double click, but when it comes to tablet or phone the double click will identify as zoom in / zoom out, therefore i change to onclick with confirmation message and here comes the problem, how should i delete it after user press ok?

> P/S: I didn't use button but by selecting the row to delete the data

current onclick code

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this order? ');");
```

Previous doubleclick delete code

```
//e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "__doPostBack('CView','Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "');");
```

the full code of it

```
protected void CView_RowDataBound(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "c=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#cccccc'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=c");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this order?');");
        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "__doPostBack('CView','Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "');");
    }
}
```

I'm still searching the answer through google. If someone else asked the same question before do share me the link. Thank you

Comment: No you should add the Onclick event for delete on the Design side!

Comment: @TheButterfly: Handle `confirm` response by assigning it to a variable. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If below line deletes the row from gridview

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "__doPostBack('CView','Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "');");
```

and you want to call above functionality on confirmation then you can do following changes.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "c=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#cccccc'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=c");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var vconfirm = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this order?'); if (vconfirm){ __doPostBack('CView','Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "');}");          
    }
```

Comment: i tried but still it doesn't delete the record. i will try with function. Anyway thanks for the help :v

Comment: oh wait you just typo! there should only 1 } but you put 2 instead. and this worked for me! thank you so much!

Comment: `"');}}");` should be `"');}");`

Comment: May be the `__doPostBack` event is not firing up. Got it there's a small typo mistake i have added an extra braces.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to assign the `OnclientClick` in `aspx` code for the button as follows

```
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="deletebtn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
             Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this order? ');" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: appreciate for your answer. but FYI, i didn't use a button to delete, i would like to click on the selected data and receive delete confirmation message before i delete the row. :)

Comment: @TheButterfly you are clicking on  a Row ? or triggering a Button to delete ?

Comment: sorry that i didn't make the question clear. What i would like to do is by clicking on the selected row to delete the data within the row.

Comment: @TheButterfly please refer this       [Link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Row-Click-event-to-GridView-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx) you may need the `selectedchanged` to trigger the Onclick

Comment: i applied 'selectedchange' before i using 'onclick' , the link is not really what i need but thanks for your effort

Comment: @TheButterfly Im understanding what you want !! Please check this if feasible try this trick!!

Comment: @TheButterfly if in design side use `Onclientclick` and write a javascript function and in that try to assign the `rowindex `value for  hidden field and add your delete confirmation code . if bool value is true return `true` and assign Rowindex value to hidden field. now after the `return true `.In server side  the selected chaged index will be triggered and in that from hidden fiel you can get row index value and try to delete the row . here is the javascript function for getting row index

Comment: `function SelectrowindexCode(row) {
        var rowData = row.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rowIndex = rowData.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("<%=hdValue.ClientID %>").value = rowIndex;
    }`

Comment: mmm, you gave me an idea. So i will give up on "onclick" on go for function call in order to achieve my want. thanks !

Comment: Sure !! np , i will be available just feel free to ask if you stuck any where Happytohelp !!

Comment: @TheButterfly make sure to accept the correct answer. so that people get his credit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="..columnname.." HeaderText="...." />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="..columname.." HeaderText="...." />
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
</Columns>
```

Then on Row DataBound

```
   protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    string item = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
    foreach (Button button in e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        if (button.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            button.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Do you want to delete " + item + "?')){ return false; };";
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Then on row deleting

```
 protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
     // delete code
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
dt.Rows[index].Delete();
ViewState["dt"] = dt;
BindGrid();
 }
```

Comment: sadly i didn't use a button to trigger the confirmation. but still i will keep it for future reference ! Thanks